# Sylius Changing "web" directory to "www" makes images not loading

Tags: symfony, sylius

I've installed Sylius and I need to change "web" directory to "www". I have followed official Symfony instructions. The problem is images of products and categories don't load. I have been digging in "config.yml" and I have changed:

```
liip_imagine:
    web_root:             %kernel.root_dir%/../www/media/image
    data_root:            %kernel.root_dir%/../www/media/image%
```

And also I have changed:

```
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        sylius_image:
            local:
                directory:  %kernel.root_dir%/../www/media/image
                create:     true
```

But it's still not working.

Do you know if it's needed to change anything else?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the trick. In order to images be shown you have to edit "app/config/config.yml":

```
liip_imagine:
    web_root:             %kernel.root_dir%/../www
    data_root:            %kernel.root_dir%/../www/media/image
```

And now images for products and categories are shown correctly.